# Upgrading the CPU in a CentOS server

Tags: centos

I have a CentOS server running moodle and owncloud service. It is running with an Intel G2030 CPU, so that's reason why it running so slowly.

Therefore, I want to upgrade the CPU. So If I change for a new CPU, will it give me compatibility problems with the CentOS kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only replace the CPU, you should be fine. If you are also upgrading the mainboard or other hardware components, you may run into driver issues, but since most hardware should be supported out of the box by an up-to-date kernel, no problem should arise. If you exchange more than the cpu, maybe do a quick search on your desired components whether they work well under linux.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm just intend replacing CPU for upgrading performance.